# HTML language code

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, lang

I have small sections of text on my site that are in French (Canadian). When I look up on the [W3schools language code reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp), I find there is only a list of specific languages but not location. Is writing `<span lang="fr-CA">` valid? Does adding the location-base of the language have any impact at all on screen-readers?

Comment: Are you using a localization framework? or just specifying the language that is in the span element?

Comment: If you look at the next [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_country_codes.asp) it describes country codes.

Comment: @JGrice you should post that as an answer, since that's what Rywek seems to be looking for

Comment: @JGrice Woops, should have seen that. Though, the question about the screen-reader impact is still up in the air.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Thanks, made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_country_codes.asp) on W3schools describes valid country codes and how to use them with language codes.

Ex: `<html lang="en-US">`

In regards to screen readers, it would depend on how the reader was implemented. Generally they would get the language from `<html>` but it is possible that some implementations may allow for the language to change over the course of the document.

The `lang` attribute can be used in any html element, as described in the HTML [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang), so `<span lang="fr-CA">` would be valid.

Comment: w3schools is not authoritative, and it is of poor quality. There is no reason to rely on their having copied the data correctly from authoritative sources *and* kept it up to date.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I realize w3schools is a poor source, but the fact that it is the not the most recent information does not cause it to be completely invalid. The OP specifically referenced the site in his post, therefore it is easiest to refer the OP to look at information on a site he is familiar with.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `<span lang="fr-CA">` is valid, but you should not expect it to provide any benefits over `<span lang="fr">` in most cases. In fact I have used a screen reader that recognized a few values for the `lang` tag but *only* when simply codes like `en` and `fr` were used.

According to HTML5 PR, the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes) value is a language code, or “language tag” as they call it, as defined in [BCP 47](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), which is a concatenation of RFCs *Tags for Identifying Languages* and *Matching of Language Tags*. It defines a rather complicated system of codes. Most of the possibilities have no use in HTML in practice, now or in the foreseeable future. The code system has been defined to meet many different needs, including bibliographic information and text databases.

Using `fr-CA` is possible in accordance with RFC 5646, clause 2.2.4. Region Subtag:

> Region subtags are used to indicate linguistic variations
>   associated    with or appropriate to a specific country, territory, or
>   region.    Typically, a region subtag is used to indicate variations
>   such as    regional dialects or usage, or region-specific spelling
>   conventions.    It can also be used to indicate that content is
>   expressed in a way    that is appropriate for use throughout a region,
>   for instance,    Spanish content tailored to be useful throughout
>   Latin America.

The subtag `CA` is the ISO 3166-1 country code for Canada, so `fr-CA` denotes French as spoken and written in Canada, i.e. Canadian French. It is possible that a screen reader that can speak French in different variants and recognizes `lang` attributes will use Canadian pronunciation for an element that has `lang="fr-CA"`. However, this is probably very theoretical and would be of little practical impact if it were actually implemented.

More realistically, such an attribute may have *other* effects. If you open an HTML document in MS Word, it will recognize `lang` attributes. Whether this has any practical impact depends on whether and how Word treats Canadian French as differently from French in general e.g. in spelling checks.